# Updating TextView from DataBinding (ViewModel) to Fragment does not work

Tags: android-fragments, viewmodel, android-databinding

I'm trying to use DataBinding (ViewModel) from Fragment, but for some reason the data doesn't want to be updated. The display is updated by resending to binding or rotating the screen.

```
binding.setViewModelDoc(modelDocWeight);
```

I change the data like this

```
modelDocWeight.setWeight(12);
```

That's how it is written in the layout

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="viewModelDoc"
        type="ru.s.uch.viewModel.ViewModelDoc" />
</data>

<TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text='@{Integer.toString(viewModelDoc.weight)}'/>
```

Binding a Model to a layout in a Fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = FragmentDocWeightInfoBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    View view = binding.getRoot().getRootView();

    modelDocWeight = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(ViewModelDoc.class);

    binding.setLifecycleOwner(this.getViewLifecycleOwner());
    binding.setViewModelDoc(modelDocWeight);
```

ViewModel

```
public class ViewModelDoc extends AndroidViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<Integer> weight = new MutableLiveData<>(0);

     public Integer getWeight() {
        return this.weight.getValue();
    }

    public void setWeight(Integer tmWeight) {
        this.weight.postValue(tmWeight);
    }
}
```

I tried different options **binding.setLifecycleOwner();** but it still doesn't work.
Please tell me what the problem may be, how to force the data to be updated in **TextView** without resending **setViewModelDoc**?